Nginx host not found in upstream "web:8000" error, for Docker container
My docker container was in a loop of restarting, so I removed that and recreated the new one (nginx image) by naming the same as the old one.
However, this new one is in "exited" status from the beginning, not able to start it.
Within the logs I'm seeing the following error:
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "web:8000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:2

Any idea on what should I do, as I'm not able to get inside of this new docker container to edit?
I've looked at my /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf file but it is empty, nothing there at all.
The other nginx files I have that has code in it are below. Should I edit one of those? How?
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

/etc/nginx/sites-available/limeguide.org

my docker-compose.yml
    version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    container_name: sozluk_backend
    command: gunicorn djdict.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 4
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static:rw
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media:rw
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ../conf/django.env
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    container_name: sozluk_nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/media
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    depends_on:
      - web
  db:
    image: postgres:15.4-alpine
    restart: always
    container_name: sozluk_db
    user: postgres
    env_file:
      - ../conf/postgres.env
  redis:
    image: redis:7.2-alpine
    restart: always
    container_name: sozluk_redis
    user: redis
  celery:
    env_file:
      - ../conf/django.env
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    container_name: sozluk_celery_worker
    command: celery -A djdict worker -l info
    volumes:
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  celery-beat:
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ../conf/django.env
    volumes:
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    container_name: sozluk_celery_beat
    command: celery -A djdict beat -l info
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:


Btw, my site was perfectly working till yesterday and it refused to connect out of nowhere without me uodating anything on the site suddenly. I managed to make it show nginx page by updating port to 80 from 8080, but not able to run the docker container that holds the project in it. limeguide.org


Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  In particular, how are you starting the two containers; are they in the same Compose file, or do they explicitly share a Docker network?

@DavidMaze How can I know which one is the case? My docker-compose.yml includes all the other docker containers if that's the question.  I'm using a public repository and here's the link to entire yml file: https://github.com/realsuayip/django-sozluk/blob/master/docker/docker-compose.yml

Are there any networks: in the file at all?  What's running in the web container; is it starting up, and is it listening on 0.0.0.0:8000?

Updated my post with full docker-compose.yml, there is no networks: Btw, my site was perfectly working till yesterday and it refused to connect out of nowhere without me uodating anything on the site suddenly. limeguide.org
